# Low search distance filter as results parameter?

Tags: low-search, geofinder

I wanted to use geofinder to do a simple distance sorted search, but it looks like it's no longer compatible with EE 2.10.1

So I wanted to see if I could use low search to produce the same results. I have a search box in which I ask visitors to enter their postcode(uk)

I can then use the gmaps plugin to geocode that postcode into latlng values (and save as stash vars).

Ideally it would be great if I could pass in those latlng values to the low_search:results tag as parameters, rather than posting them as hidden inputs with the search (as I don't have the values until the results page).

Does that make sense, and is there any way of doing it with low_search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Distance filter parameters as regular parameters on the Results tag, so that shouldn't be an issue. You might encounter some parse order issues with using tags as another tag's parameter value, but you could work around that with using an embed.

Comment: Thanks Low. Should this work? (rep_lat and rep_lng are the channel fields that store the lat/lng data) and I can see that the embed lat/lng are being passed through. Can I use distance:from as a param or do I need to somehow spoof a query?

`{exp:low_search:results
  channel="local_rep"
  distance:from="{embed:lat}|{embed:lng}"
  distance:to="{rep_lat}|{rep_lng}"
}
  <p>{title} {low_search_distance}</p>
{/exp:low_search:results}`

Comment: Use the field names without the curly brackets: `distance:to="rep_lat|rep_lng"` -- then it should work.

Comment: Thank you! Ok I've done that and added a 'no results' condition - I get no results:
`{exp:low_search:results
  channel="local_rep"
  distance:from="{embed:lat}|{embed:lng}"
  distance:to="rep_lat|rep_lng"
}
  {if no_results}NO RESULTS{/if}
  <p>{title} {low_search_distance}</p>

{/exp:low_search:results}`
Have I missed something?

Comment: Open up a thread on [GetSat](https://getsatisfaction.com/low). This isn't the ideal place to debug this.